# change text size in textbox in html

Tags: html

How to change the textbox size in html. Like the one in twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter's default twitting box is using `<textarea>`. From Firebug, it's something like

```
textarea.twitterBox {
 border:1px solid #AAAAAA;
 padding:4px 2px;
 -x-system-font:none;
 font-family:'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
 font-size:1.15em;
 height:2.5em;
 line-height:1.1;
 overflow:auto;
 width:515px;
}
```

PS: Not sure if the theme affects the above though

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS property `font-size`?